# Code Behind Xamarin forms launch a function in another page

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have 2 ContentView in MyWordPage.Xaml which are  MyWordListView and AddWordsView

My MyWordPage.Xaml looks like this :

```
<ContentView      x:Name="MyWordListView" >

    <CollectionView  x:Name="ListOfWords"  IsVisible="False"
SelectionMode="Single"    >
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <LinearItemsLayout  Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout >
            <Label  Text="{Binding .}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentView>

<ContentView    IsVisible="False"  x:Name="AddWordsView"  />

<pv:PancakeView  HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End"  Margin="0,0,10,150" Padding="10" CornerRadius="10">

    <Image HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Aspect="AspectFit" />
    <pv:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnChangeViewButton"  />
    </pv:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>

</pv:PancakeView>

<Grid/>
```

If MyWordListView is visible, AddWordsView is not visible and vise versa.

The App starts with MyWordListPage visible and MyWordPage.xaml.cs looks like this:

```
   public MyWordPage()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    
    // My second content view AddWordsView take content form a content page 
    // this content page name is MyAddWordPage
    AddWordsView.Content = new MyAddWordPage().Content; 
    
    //My list of words  
    ListOfWords.ItemsSource = new List<string>()
    {
        "New York",
        "London",
        "Mumbai",
        "Chicago"                    
    };        
    
    }

 //I navigate between the 2 View With an Overlay Button that make
 //each one of View visible thanks to a boolean 

bool ViewChange=false;
void OnChangeViewButton(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)

{

if (ViewChange==false)

{

AddWordsView.IsVisible=true;
MyWordListView.IsVisible=false;
ViewChange=!ViewChange;
}

else
{

AddWordsView.IsVisible=false;
MyWordListView.IsVisible=true;
ViewChange=!ViewChange;
}


}

OnUpdateMyList()
{
// Here I do things to refresh my list
}
```

MyAddWordPage.xaml.cs  looks like this :

```
  public MyWordPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

void OnInsertWord(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}
```

What I would like to do :

In `MyAddWordPage.xaml.cs` when clicking on a button to launch the function `OnInsertWord()` I would like to launch the function `OnUpdateMyList()` in `MyWordPage.xaml.cs` in order to refresh My collectionView in `MyWordListView`

Thanks for your help

Comment: first, please format your code so that it is readable.  Your erratic indention and whitespace make this incredibly difficult to read.  Second, you are using "View" and "Page" very inconsistently.  If a Page contains 2 Views, and one of those Views is also named "Page" then its difficult to follow your logic. Third when discussing interactions between two pages, its very helpful to describe how you navigate beteen them.  Are you using PushAsync, PushModalAysnc, or some other mechanism?

Comment: @Jason thanks, I have updated the post. I navigate bettwen them with button that overlay the both View.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, you can achieve this by overriding `OnAppearing` method.

The `OnAppearing` method is executed after the `ContentPage` is laid out, but just before it becomes visible.So, you can rebind the list to the collectionview in this method. Therefore, this is a good place to set the content of Xamarin.Forms views.

Here is the code in `MyWordPage.xaml.cs`:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // My second content view AddWordsView take content form a content page 
            // this content page name is MyAddWordPage
            AddWordsView.Content = new MyAddWordPage().Content;
            //My list of words  

        }
        //Create a list
        List<string> list = new List<string>()
        {
          "New York",
          "London",
          "Mumbai",
          "Chicago"
         };
        
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            ListOfWords.ItemsSource = list;
        }
        //I navigate between the 2 View With an Overlay Button that make
        //each one of View visible thanks to a boolean 

        bool ViewChange = false;
        void OnChangeViewButton(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewChange == false)

            {
                AddWordsView.IsVisible = true;
                MyWordListView.IsVisible = false;
                ViewChange = !ViewChange;
            }
            else
            {
                AddWordsView.IsVisible = false;
                MyWordListView.IsVisible = true;
                ViewChange = !ViewChange;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code in `MyWordPage.Xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App5.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="MyWordListView">
            <CollectionView  x:Name="ListOfWords"  SelectionMode="Single"    >
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout  Orientation="Vertical" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout >
                            <Label  Text="{Binding .}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
        
        <ContentView    IsVisible="False"  x:Name="AddWordsView" >
            <Label Text="Here is the text."></Label>
        </ContentView>

        <StackLayout>
            <Button Clicked="OnChangeViewButton"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
        
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The method OnAppearing does not work. I have add a Console.Writeline and it is not showed  MyWordListView is set to visible

Comment: That might be something wrong on your side, it works well on my side. Could you provide more information? Thanks.

Comment: When I click on OnChangeViewButton() button to make MyWordListView visible or not the console.Write in OnAppearing() does ne show

Comment: I reedited my answer and uploaded the code in MyWordPage.Xaml. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I am sorry I think, there is a miss understand. In MyAddWordPage.xaml.cs when clicking on a button to launch the function OnInsertWord() I would like to launch the function OnUpdateMyList() in MyWordPage.xaml.cs in order to refresh My collectionView in MyWordListView

Comment: OnAppearing() does not work when MyWordListView is set to visible because I have put a console writeline in it. The print is not showed

Comment: I found a better way to achieve this. You can change the code  `List<string> list = new List<string>()` to `ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>()` . It represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added or removed, or when the whole list is refreshed. Here is the website about ObservableCollection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: I will look it and see how I can adapt

Comment: I think you just change the `List` to `ObservableCollection` it can work , `ObservableCollection` can notify the items change automatically just like MVVM. I made a demo on my side when I added the items into the `ObservableCollection` it changed on the frontpage automatically without refreshing the `CollectionView`.

Comment: My ListView need to be refreshed from Addwords. How can it be notify ?

Comment: when you add items to the `ObservableCollection` , it can refresh itself.

Comment: the ObservableCollection List only exist in  MyWordPage. In my MyAddWordPage I store data ( I use sql database to store new data) and in MyWordPage i read the data (from my sql database) and use the ObservableCollection List to display it . This is why I need to launch the function OnUpdateMyList() in MyWordPage.xaml.cs in order to refresh MycollectionView

Comment: I have an idea is that you can use the MessagingCenter to notify the OnUpdateMyList() method when you click the button.

Comment: How can you do it ? please